# How to make disable onclick element of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a table with tr's like

```
<tr onclick="doprocess1()">
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td><button onclick="doprocess2()"</td>  <!--I want to disable the clickevent of the <tr> here -->
</tr>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop [**event bubbling**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

***Note***

Make it [**unobtrusive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

```
<tr id="tr1">
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td>Some data</td>
   <td><button id="bt1">Click</button></td>  <!--I want to disable the clickevent of the <tr> here -->
</tr>


$(function(){
    $("#tr1").click(function(){
    });
    $("#bt1").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<td><button onclick="doprocess2(event);"</td>

 function doprocess2(evt) {

    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    // your existing code goes here
}
```

This works on Firefox, Chrome, and IE9.  Not sure about older versions of IE where the "event" object doesn't get passed. (Use window.event instead).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. 
In your case the easiest is probably the following:

define doprocess2 like this:

```
function doprocess2(e) {
    e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation() || (e.cancelBubble = true);
    ...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
onclick="doprocess2(event);"
```

This will work in all modern browsers and also ie6, ie7 & ie8

Here is a workable example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function doprocess1() { alert('tr'); }
function doprocess2(e) {
    e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation() || (e.cancelBubble = true);
    alert('td');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr onclick="doprocess1();">
    <td>click tr</td>
    <td><button onclick="doprocess2(event);">click td only</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```