# How to prevent events from stacking-up when assigned multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have a dynamically created list and I want to add for all its elements a click event on a delete button.

Every time I add an element to the list, I add an event to all the list elements, but for older elements the events stack-up instead of being replaced because I ran this multiple time:

```
function(e) {
                    $(".tr-del").on('click',
                            function(e) {
                                alert("delete");
                                $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
                            });
```

The results is that for older elements you need to press the delete button multiple times.

How can I have only one event even if the event association is ran multiple times. I don't know when the last name is added is made so I need to run this more than once.

**Working code is here: I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HnqE/2/)** for showing/testing this situation.

Comment: I checked the JSFiddle, the delete alert is coming multiple times, is that the problem? That is the click event is attached multiple times to the element?

Comment: @Vinoth Yes, that's the problem,

Comment: cool, I added the answer. Please check :)

Comment: Also this question might help:http://stackoverflow.com/q/4666013/1577343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click event is added multiple times to the element. If you want to attach the event only once, then add the `off('click')`before adding the `on('click')`. This will remove the existing click event and add a new one.

```
   $(".tr-del").off('click').on('click',
                    function(e) {
                        alert("delete");
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
                    });
```

I also updated the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5HnqE/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out ..this should solve your problem..
just add it add the end of the click function

```
li.find(".tr-del").on('click',
function(e) {
    alert("delete");
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#yourIdAttribute").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
     alert("delete"); // Or do something !!
     $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast"); //This is to disappear the tag with #yourIdAttribute
 });
```

*So using off('click') and then on('click') is the best option to prevent the event from stacking up !!! Every time you surpass the function $().on('click', function(e){}) or $().click(function(e){}), it's gonna stack 1 new event e to that tag < id = "yourIdAttribute"> . First time you click, it call 1 time, next click , call 2, and then 3 and so on !!!